# python HTML parsing issue

Tags: python, arrays, parsing, design-patterns

Given an html page, I would like to only get an array of variables like this (id1, value1), (id2, value2), ...., the file is given like this:

```
    <div class="col m3 s12 col_title"><div class="font-small grey-text truncate content" title="value1">value1</div></div>
    <div class="col m7 s12 col_id"><div class="content wrap">id1</div></div>
```

every value is followed by a "content wrap" id.
I was thinking of something like:

match = re.compile('title="(.+?)".+?wrap"(.+?)"').findall(source)

---

This is an example:

```
<li class="collection-item Ids ">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col m3 s12 col_title"><div class="font-small grey-text truncate content" title="filename1">filename1</div></div>
    <div class="col m7 s12 col_id"><div class="content wrap">6000bc3211af43d7</div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="col m2 s12 col_time">
        <div class="content">
            <a href="http://test.com/test.php" target="_blank" class="secondary-content pull-right">
                <span class="font-small grey-text" title="filex">test</span>
                <i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true" title="filey"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use scraping libraries like `beautiful soup`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: example with filenames and values like an md5 or a hash :         <div class="col m3 s12 col_title"><div class="font-small grey-text truncate content" title="filename1">filename1</div></div>
        <div class="col m7 s12 col_id"><div class="content wrap">6000bc3211af43d7</div></div>


        <div class="col m3 s12 col_title"><div class="font-small grey-text truncate content" title="filename2">filename2</div></div>
        <div class="col m7 s12 col_id"><div class="content wrap">32475af45c6bc432</div></div>

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), it should have everything you need for parsing HTML.

For exemple, you could use :

```
# open the html from the website or from a file, check the doc
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(yoururl), "lxml") 
result = soup.find_all(class_="content wrap").get_text()
```

Here, result would be an array containing all the text contents inside the elements that have a "content wrap" class.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the example for id1 and value1?
I have a idea :D

> \w{1,}\d{1,}<
>   And getting from 1 to len(match)-1 
>   It can not true.

Comment: an example would like like this:         <div class="col m3 s12 col_title"><div class="font-small grey-text truncate content" title="filename1">filename1</div></div>
        <div class="col m7 s12 col_id"><div class="content wrap">6000bc3211af43d7</div></div>


        <div class="col m3 s12 col_title"><div class="font-small grey-text truncate content" title="filename2">filename2</div></div>
        <div class="col m7 s12 col_id"><div class="content wrap">32475af45c6bc432</div></div>

Answer (score 0):

Building on TheWildHealer's answer, you can use the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://websitehere.com").text, "lxml")
results = []
for row in soup.find_all(class_ = "row"):
    titleText = row.find(class_ = "col_title").get_text()
    idText = row.find(class_ = "col_id").get_text()
    results.append((idText, titleText))
```

Comment: Can you please check that it works with the example I just added to get filename1 and corresponding content wrap: 6000bc3211af43d7 ? thanks.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You can (and should) read more about BeautifulSoup as well, which is linked in the other answer.